# count repeated row values without breaks

Tags: mysql, sql, sequence, repeat

I want to count repeated values in rows one by one without breaks. If it breaks with NULL value, then count it again from zero.

It is a simple table consists from action_id and event_code.

```
| id | action_id  | event_code |
--------------------------------
| 1  |     1      |    100     |
| 2  |     1      |    200     |
| 3  |     1      |    300     |
| 4  |     2      |    100     |
| 5  |     2      |    300     |
| 6  |     3      |    100     |
| 7  |     3      |    200     |
| 8  |     3      |    400     |
```

Then it groups by action_id (with SQL query) to:

```
| action_id | c100 | c200 | c300 | c400 |
-----------------------------------------
|     1     |  1   |  1   |  1   |  0   |
|     2     |  1   |  0   |  1   |  0   |
|     3     |  1   |  1   |  0   |  1   |
```

and as a result:

```
| action_id | c100 | e100_r | c200 | e200_r | c300 | e300_r | c400 | e400_r |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     1     |  1   |   3    |  1   |   1    |  1   |   2    |  0   |   0    |
|     2     |  1   |   3    |  0   |   0    |  1   |   2    |  0   |   0    |
|     3     |  1   |   3    |  1   |   1    |  0   |   0    |  1   |   1    |
```

or

```
| id | action_id  | event_code | rep_count |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  |     1      |    100     |     3     |
| 2  |     1      |    200     |     1     |
| 3  |     1      |    300     |     2     |
| 4  |     2      |    100     |     3     |
| 5  |     2      |    300     |     2     |
| 6  |     3      |    100     |     3     |
| 7  |     3      |    200     |     1     |
| 8  |     3      |    400     |     1     |
```

Is it possible?

EDIT 1:
c100 - couunter of event_code == 100 and e100_r - repeats of  event_code == 100

EDIT 2:
Rows breaks by zero (0)

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you specifically stuck?

Comment: I see 3 different results and none null to match the title description. Which one you want? 
    Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Query for the second table like:

Comment: what is `e100_r `? what the `e` and `r` mean

Comment: *"If it breaks with NULL value, then count it again from zero."* Your example does not cover that case you most likely mean a `zero (0)` instead off `NULL` .. in SQL`0`and `NULL` are **NOT** the same

Comment: Ok, there is a subquery and it gives NULL values. In my question this is zero(0)

Comment: Sorry but your question isnt clear and you havent show any attempt, this isnt a free code service. Read the links above to learn how improve your question.

Comment: c100 - couunter of event_code == 100 and e100_r - repeats of  event_code == 100

Comment: My suggestion split your question in multiple questions. For example do you know how get the first result? groups by action_id?  That alone is a question.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with simple `SELECT`, `JOIN`, etc. However you can write a procedure with `WHILE` and `IF` statements, which than you can call and it will output something like this.